# What is the hot key to show or apply quick fixes in VS Code?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Simple question. There's a yellow lamp on the picture below. Which hot key I have to use in order to apply/see suggestions given by VS code ?
[image]

What I expect to see is
[image]

I'm using macOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press on the gear > Keyboard Shortcuts > search for "quick fix"

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> on my Linux system.

Comment: @user I literally told him how to get to the list of all shortcuts in its vscode installation

Comment: cool it helped me a lot - on my mac it's cmd + .